# Mysql syntax error in python

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

I have 5 MySQL columns. I want to insert data into my columns with a for loop. But I always get an error.

**SQL query:**

```
for i in range(5):
    sql = "INSERT INTO fighters({},{}) VALUES(%s,%s) WHERE clan=%s".format("shot_" + str(i), "damage_" + str(i))
    cur.execute(sql, (shot, damage, clanname)
    conn.commit()
```

**Error:**

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE clan='blacks'' at line 1")
```

Comment: What does this mean?  "I want insert data to my dynamic columns".  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: i have 5 column and all name is different its not dynamic,but need insert with for loop.but i cannt fix this error

Comment: Can you please provide the structure of the table where you want to do the insert as well as the complete code showing how you set the shot, damage and clanname variables?

Comment: Alex thank you fixed.insert its wrong command ,we must update :) hd1 helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to update rather than insert:

```
sql = "UPDATE FIGHTERS SET shot_{0} = %s, damage_{1} = %s WHERE clan=%s".format("shot_" + str(i), "damage_" + str(i))
cur.execute(sql, (shot, damage, clanname,))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i have less reputation because of i cannt accepted (((.but you very helped mee thank you very much

Comment: No worries, glad I could be of assistance.